# qt c++ metatype typeflag don't match issue

Tags: c++, qt

I meet a **qt metatype** issue.

I have a `const pointer` to a class derived from `qobject` and want to put into `QVariant` like below:

```
QVariant::fromValue(objectPointer)
```

I have declared the meta type of derived class using:  `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(const QDrivedClass *)` in the header file (.h) of the derived class.

But at run time, I got below error:

```
QMetaType::registerType: Binary compatibility break. Type flags for type 'const QDrivedClass *' [1093] don't match. Previously registered TypeFlags(0x10c), now registering TypeFlags(0x104).
```

I checked the whole project and find there're a line of code below may cause this issue:

```
 qRegisterMetaType<T *>(QByteArray("const ") + QByteArray(T::staticMetaObject.className()) +
                   QByteArray("*"));
```

If I comment above code, the `Typeflag` mismatch issue will be fixed. But it will cause another issue since we need to use signal/slot of the derived class.

Can anyone give me some advice why the `qRegisterMetaType` and `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` will have different type flags for the const pointer to a class derived from `QObject` and how to fix it?

Comment: You are mixing const and non-const types in your qRegisterMetaType call, which, I think, is not a good idea.

Comment: Anyhow, the type flags seem to be "movable + pointer to QObject", and the other just "movable". Does your derived class have a `Q_OBJECT` macro in its declaration?

Comment: Yes, the drived class have a Q_OBJECT macro in its declaration. And the drived object is exported in a dll.

Answer (score 0):

E4z9, thanks for pointing out mixing the const and non-const types.

That's the root cause of the type mismatch issue.

I changed the code as below:

```
qRegisterMetaType <const T *> (QByteArray("const ") + QByteArray(T::staticMetaObject.className()) + QByteArray("*"));
```

Then the type mismatch issue get fixed.

Comment:  great that you found the issue